# what are the different between i'm grew up and I am raised?

Tags: expressions

I  saw this expression here:
[Parenting beta](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/34220/using-scare-tactics-to-get-children-to-obey)

**i'm grew up myself**

I am raised me myself

on  spanish is :

**Crecí yo mismo**

Me crié yo mismo

I am try said that "myself i grew up alone without parents , that myself made my future all and I was independent"

i would like explain thing similar but I would like sound like american people from US.

what example are more common in US people?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both your sentences are grammatically incorrect.

You could say something like

> I grew up on my own without parents

or

> I was raised by myself/grandmother, etc.

Comment: +1.  But you should say *Both your sentences* rather than *Your both sentences*.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm Spanish too but ...

I think that you've got a pair of errors in your initial expressions. The correct tense is **simple past**.

> I grew up on my own. 
> I was raised by none but me.  (To offer a
>   different sentence from the one pointed by @Maryam)

I'm not sure if you can use "raised by myself". 
It sounds strange in Spanish too: me crie a mi mismo.

In relation with the rest of your enquire, let me show you an interesting adjective

**[self-made](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/self-made)** (US)

> successful as a result of your own effort:
>   *a self-made man/woman*

Comment: +1 for *I grew up on my own*.   **on my own** is truly idiomatic. **by none but me** however is stilted.  That is not likely to be said by any contemporary speaker.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Well, to be fair, I don't deserve it. I alredy knew that expression but I have taken that part from Maryam's answer. You should upvote her

Answer (score 1):

The simplest idiomatic statement using **raise** is

> I raised myself.

Another variant using **grow**:

> I grew up on my own.